# Power BI: How to summarize values?

Tags: database, powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a table that contains customer survey data. I have created categories for strength and weakness of the company based on the responses.
[image]

I want to score the strengths accordingly. Strength 1 columns is scored 3, strength 2 as 2 and strength 3 as 1.

I have created the output table that I want in excel.

[image]

I need guidance on how to do the same in power bi.

Comment: can you please explain behind numbers like in first row: 66 27 23 275

Answer (score 0):

In powerbi create an additional DictCategory table with all strength Category. Setup inactive relationships to your survey table (Str1 Category/ Str2 Category etc);
Next create measures:

```
Strength1 = calculate( count('Survey'), USERELATIONSHIP(DictCategory[Category],'Survey'[Str1 Category]))
Strength2 = calculate( count('Survey'), USERELATIONSHIP(DictCategory[Category],'Survey'[Str2 Category]))
Strength3 = calculate( count('Survey'), USERELATIONSHIP(DictCategory[Category],'Survey'[Str3 Category]))
```

Last one:

```
SumOfStrength = [Strength1] * 3 + [Strength2]*2 + [Strength3]
```

Drag everything to table visualization (Strength Category from DictCategory),